# Optional properties in swift

Tags: swift, properties, option-type

If I have property like:

```
var animatedImagesView:JSAnimatedImagesView?
```

And eventually it gets initialized at the proper time, do I need to just keep using `!` to unwrap it ad nauseum when I want to do something to it? For instance:

```
self.animatedImagesView!.reloadData()
```

Usually I unwrap optionals like:

```
 if let dailySleepTime:AnyObject = uw_JSON["daily_sleep_time"] {
    self.settings.dailySleepTime = dailySleepTime as String
 } else {
    log.warning("\n Error finding attr in \(request)\n")
 }
```

but I can't just go around casting my properties to constants in the same way right? I'm not complaining, I'm just wondering if I'm using the exclamation point correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to define `animatedImageView` as an implicitly unwrapped optional to begin with:

```
var animatedImagesView: JSAnimatedImagesView!
```

This is common when dealing with Cocoa .nib objects in Interface Builder, because the View can't be initialized until it is unarchived from the .nib, but you know that it will always be initialized before you use it.

I hate using the `!` in general, because it is a runtime error just waiting to happen, but IB objects are one of the few places where its use seems both legitimate and necessary. Otherwise, your two other options are the ones that you have already found - unwrapping it every time using `if let...` (which is safest, but a pain in the a**), or using the `!` every time that you use it, which isn't any safer than just declaring it using `!` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, declare it as follows:

```
          var animatedImagesView:JSAnimatedImagesView!
```

That *implicitly unwrapped optional* will obviate the need to constantly "bang" dereference it, but be sure it is never nil at any time accessed.

It's a great way to specify IBOutlets you know will always be initialized from the nib or storyboard before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize it at the correct time (for example in any of the lifecycle methods, or in the constructor for that matter) you could just use `!` instead of `?` for the property declaration. I myself usually only use `?` for stuff which I dont necessarily know will have a value at all times during my lifecycle.

If the latter is the case for you as well, you need to continue using `?` since you can't guarantee you have a value stored. And you should also use the `if let myVar = myVar { .. }` syntax if you do multiple calls to the variable.